# Why I am getting ERROR in Flutter While adding ad

Tags: flutter, admob

Why I am getting errors in flutter while adding ad in a flutter :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0.

Comment: Can you share build.gradle file

Comment: I just had to change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in my build.gradle file. (YourApp\android\build.gradle).

`compileSdkVersion from 29 to 30
targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30`

after this change, it started to run.

Answer (score 0):

Update your compileSdkVersion to 31